# Symfony 5 : how to bind enties in a CollectionType?

Tags: php, symfony

i'm having trouble using CollectionType for the first time. What i want is to create/update a Client and be able to add new ClientOptionsAbonnement to him.

I got a relation between two entites :

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=ClientOptionsAbonnement::class, mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
private $clientOptionsAbonnement;
```

I use a ClientType :

```
->add('clientOptionsAbonnement', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => ClientOptionsAbonnementType::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'delete_empty' => true,
    'label' => false
 ])
```

I use a ClientOptionsType :

```
->add('client', EntityType::class,[
    'class' => 'App\Entity\Clients',
    'choice_label' => 'id'
])
```

It, indeed, displays my client and allows me to add options. But what i need is to be able to link my client to his options without having to select his ID in selectbox.

How can i say to Symfony : "these options goes to the client binded to ClientType" ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

'by_reference' => false on ClientType options was the answer.